# Normalization for particle in a ring

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, normalization

If $Ae^{ik\phi}$ is a solution,  I used
$$\int_0^{2\pi}|\psi|^2rd\phi=1$$
because, along a ring, the total probability is 1. So I took the element to be $rd\phi$. This gave me a normalization constant of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi r}}$.

But in the solution, they got $A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

That is, $$\psi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi r}}e^{ik\phi}$$

Comment: It seems that you are right to me. Are you sure that you are not given a ring of radius $1$?

Comment: Yes. radius is r. In wikipedia, both normalization constants are mentioned

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_ring

Comment: You don't actually ask anything here... is the question about why they omit the $r$ from the solution?

Comment: Yes @DavidZ I guess I forgot to convert psi into polar coordinates

Comment: Your normalization integral is wrong.   And your proposed solution may be wrong depending on what you mean by $k$, which you never define for us.  (Those comments are intended to be hints, not criticisms.)

Comment: So it seems the concensus is that the OP is correct, you need the r in the normalisation, and Wikipedia has a typo in the second section.

Comment: @BruceGreetham k is like a quantum number or a constant. But the problem is (i guess), if i use psi(theta), then r shouldnt be there. If i use r, my psi has to be polar coordinates.

Comment: I see what you are saying, so wiki is not a typo - it is the first section which is wrong and needs rewriting. An easy mistake to make.

Comment: Unless one actually wants to integrate over $r$ (for instance, to normalize the mode), it does not make sense to include it in the expression. In the case of the ring the mode is completely defined as a function of $\phi$, so it does not need the $r$. The $r$ can be removed everywhere. And $k$ is obvious the modal index: a dimensionless integer.

Comment: If $\phi$ is an angle, your exponent has units (it shouldn't have units). Could this be a typo, and the wave function should be:
\begin{equation}
\psi=Ae^{ikr\phi}
\end{equation}

Comment: hint-see...ref.<http://web.iitd.ac.in/~pramitc/Lectures%2010-13_Particle%20on%20a%20ring%20and%20sphere.pdf>